# How to add array of dictionaries from NSArray to Existing NSMutableArray in swift?

Tags: ios, swift2

In my project I have one NSMutableArray and NSArray named logOrderMutArray and openOrderArray, here I want to merge the openOrderArray with logOrderMutArray based on same "AccountNumber". If both array have same "AccountNumber" means I want to replace the particular index in logOrderMutArray with openOrderArray index else if "AccountNumber" was not same in some index means I want to add the openOrderArray to logOrderMutArray.

But I have made some mistakes. How can I solve the issue?

Here is my code:

```
func mergeOrderAndOpenOrderArrayData() {
    let validateMutArray = NSMutableArray()
    for i in 0..<self.logOrderMutArray.count {
        var dictMutableCopy = NSDictionary()
        var editDict = NSMutableDictionary()
        for j in 0..<self.openOrderArray.count {
            var newDict = NSDictionary()
            if let logOrderfips:NSNumber = (logOrderMutArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "FIPS") as? NSNumber {
                if let openOrderfips:NSNumber = (openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "FIPS") as? NSNumber {
                    if let logOrderAccNum:String = (logOrderMutArray[i] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "AccountNumber") as? String {
                        if let openOrderAccNum:String = (openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "AccountNumber") as? String {
                            if logOrderfips == openOrderfips && logOrderAccNum == openOrderAccNum {
                                dictMutableCopy = logOrderMutArray[i] as! NSDictionary
                                editDict = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: dictMutableCopy)
                                newDict = openOrderArray[j] as! NSDictionary
                                editDict["newlyAdded"] = newDict
                                logOrderMutArray.replaceObject(at: i, with: editDict)
                            }
                            else {
                                logOrderMutArray.add(openOrderArray[j])
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Horrible *objective-c-ish* code. Please use Swift native types, not `NS(Mutable)Array / Dictionary`, `NSNumber`, and API like `valueForKey`, and `as AnyObject` casts. And fast enumeration is more efficient than the index based for loops.

Comment: Bro because this is an existing project some one developed before, If I am update to latest version means i am facing lot of issues.Please can you help me for my question..@vadian